# How to write multiple training settings in PyTorch Lightning

Tags: pytorch, quantization-aware-training, pytorch-lightning

I want to iteratively quantize my model. That means that after the normal training loop which is usually implemented in `training_step` I would like to iteratively quantize some of the parameters and retrain the model for a couple of steps.

I don't really see how this would be done in Lightning. I could add a new instance to the class but then I would have to write the training loop myself again?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you could add something like this to `training_step`:

```py
step = self.global_step
if step % quantization_period == 0 and step > 0:
    self.submodules[step // quantization_period].half()
```

You can also override `LightningModule.on_epoch_end(self)` to do something after every training epoch.